# Closure of $\langle\sigma\rangle$ in $\text{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb F}_q / \mathbb F_q)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

We know that $$G_n = \text{Gal}({\mathbb{F}}_{q^n} / \mathbb{F}_q) \cong \mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z,$$
where the Frobenius $\sigma_n$ of $\mathbb F_{q^n}$ is mapped to $1 \in \mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$.

$G := \text{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb{F}}_q / \mathbb{F}_q)$ is the inverse limit of the $G_n$, which is $\hat {\mathbb Z} \cong \lim_n \mathbb Z / n\mathbb Z \cong \prod_p \mathbb Z_p$. $G$ is topologically generated by $\sigma$, the Frobenius on $\bar{\mathbb F}_q$, i.e. $\overline{\langle\sigma\rangle} = G$.

Now for the question: what does $G\backslash\langle\sigma\rangle$ actually contain?

Comment: Well, an example of an element in $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ which isn't in $\langle (1,..., 1, 1,...) \rangle$ isn't difficult to write down... But the real point is that non-closed subgroups of profinite groups are complicated and in the case of Galois theory, they're much less useful...

Comment: It seems you are asking how to write down the elements of $\widehat{\mathbf Z}$ that are not in $\mathbf Z$. Is that correct?

Comment: One way of describing such elements is to consider "numbers" of the form
$$S=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k k!,$$  where the coefficients $a_k$ are integers in the range $0\le a_k\le k$. Let's denote $F_m=\Bbb{F}_{q^{m!}}$, so $\overline{\Bbb{F}_q}$ is the nested union of the fields $F_1\subset F_2\subset F_3\subset\cdots$. Let $\sigma^S$ be the automorphism such that its restriction to $F_m$ is the Frobenius raised to the power
$$S_m=\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}a_k k!.$$
Because $S_\ell\equiv S_m\pmod {m!}$ for all $\ell>m$, this is a well defined automorphism of the nested union.

Comment: (cont'd) $\sigma^S$ is not an element of $\langle\sigma\rangle$ whenever infinitely many of the coefficients $a_k$ are non-zero. That is, whenever $S$ is not an integer.

Comment: Oops. I need to add the condition that we also want $a_k<k$ for infinitely many indices $k$. For otherwise $\sigma^S$ is a negative power of $\sigma$.

Comment: @KCd more what those elements correspond to in the Galois group, like described in the answer.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for the detailed comment! I wonder why you use $\mathbb F_{q^{m!}}$ instead of just $\mathbb F_{q^m}$? Just so that $S_l \equiv S_m (\text{mod } m!)$? Further, can you elaborate why we need $a_k < k$ for infinitely many indices? It doesn't seem obvious to me.

Comment: @foaly Jyrki is using the sequence of fields with factorial degrees so they are *totally ordered* and include all finite fields inside of them as subfields.  If you use instead all the fields $\mathbf F_{q^m}$ for $m = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, \ldots$ then those fields are not totally ordered by containment, just as the subgroups $m\mathbf Z$ of $\mathbf Z$ are not totally ordered by containment but the subgroups $m!\mathbf Z$ are totally ordered and every subgroup contains $m!\mathbf Z$ for all large $m$ (this collection of subgroups of $\mathbf Z$ is "cofinal" in all subgroups).

Comment: @foaly What KCd said. The reason for wanting $a_k<k$ infinitely often is that otherwise, for example, we may have $S_m\equiv-1\pmod{m!}$ for all $m$. Should that be the case then $\sigma^S=\sigma^{-1}$. In other words, requiring $a_k>0$ for inifinitely many $k$ means that there does not exist a positive integer $n$ such that $S_m\equiv n\pmod{m!}$ for all $m$. Requiring $a_k<k$ infinitely often achieves the same for negative integers $n$. We need both to conclude that $\sigma^S$ is not a power of $\sigma$.

Comment: Just check what kind of sequence of coefficients $a_k$ is required to get for example $S_m=m!-1$ for all $m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume that $q = p$ is a prime for simplicity of notation. Let $l$ be an another prime and note that we have
$$
G_{l}:=\lim_{n}\mathrm{Gal}({\mathbb{F}}_{p^{l^{n}}}/\mathbb{F}_{p}) = \lim_{n} \mathbb{Z}/l^{n}\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}_{l}
$$
which corresponds to *$l$-part* of $\hat{\mathbb{Z}} = \prod_{p}\mathbb{Z}_{p}$.
Choose any element $\alpha = a_{0} + a_{1}l + a_{2} l^{2} + \cdots \in \mathbb{Z}_{l} \backslash \mathbb{Z}$, then the elements corresponds to $\mu \in G_{l}$ that act as $\mathrm{Frob}_{l}^{\alpha_{k}}$ on $\mathbb{F}_{p^{l^{k}}}$ with $\alpha_{k} = a_{0} + a_{1}l + \cdots + a_{k}l^{k}$ for all $k\geq 0$.
We can lift $\mu$ to $\tilde{\mu} \in G$ under the surjective map $G \twoheadrightarrow G_{l}$, and that element is not in $\langle \sigma\rangle$
because of the choice of $\alpha$ ($\alpha \not \in \mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: Thank you, this shows a very clearly and simply how an element in $\hat{\mathbb Z}$ might correspond to one in $G$. Further any $\mu \in G$ is a preimage of such an element (ofc with $\alpha$ possibly $\in \mathbb Z$), so a product of $\mu_l \in G_l \forall l$. So the products of these elements are actually all the elements in $G$, if I am not mistaken?

Comment: @foaly Yes, that's what I thought.